# Convert HH:MM TT to Time and append onto date

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a column that holds a string time (i.e. 8:00 AM) and I need to convert that to an actual Time and be able to append it onto a DateTime field (which is in DateTime format, not string).

**Example:**
Date field = 2019-06-25 00:00:00.000
Time field = 8:00 AM
Desired result: 2019-06-25 08:00:00.000

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this in SQL?

I know some people still suggest doing it in code, but I'm writing a query that does a comparison between two DateTime fields (one of which has the integrated DateTime with the proper time and the other in which the date and time are separate)

Answer (score 3):

Using DATETIME + `CAST(timevariable AS DATETIME)` will return your expected result:

```
DECLARE @Time AS VARCHAR (10) = '8:00 AM'
DECLARE @DateField AS DATETIME = '2019-06-25 00:00:00.000';

SELECT @DateField + CAST(@time AS DATETIME)
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e1fa57b0d3a38b094d6348e81d1adb65)

It is also work with [`1:00 PM`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=761b9a74f4fd8f95eeb06d2559fc0a01)

Comment: @Ryan If it is solved your problem, please consider to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043)